# SQL Query to find more than 1 non alphanumeric chars in a string

Tags: sql, alphanumeric

Just a version 2 of the above query…

Surname GivenName
ABC      x.yz
ABc x.y.z
ABC     X.*YZ
A*.BC    xyz

The query needs to get me the surname and givenname which have more than 1 non alphanumeric characters together(one after the other). In this case the output will be

abc x.*yz 
a*.BC xyz

How would I find just the names that have 2 non alphanumeric chars together(one after the other)

Comment: "I know how to find if there are more than 1 non alphanumeric chars but not sure how to find if there are more than 1 non alphanumeric chars?" - You are contradicting yourself?

Comment: I meant I know how to find non alphanumeric chars but not sure how to find only those with more than 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want rows where either column has > 1 non-alphanumeriuc:

```
select
    Surname, 
    GivenName
from 
    T
where
    patindex('%[^A-Z0-9]%[^A-Z0-9]%', Surname) 
    + patindex('%[^A-Z0-9]%[^A-Z0-9]%', GivenName) > 0
```

Comment: Just a version 2 of the above query…

Surname GivenName
ABC      x.yz
ABc x.y.z
ABC     X.*YZ
A*.BC    xyz

The query needs to get me the surname and givenname which have more than 1 non alphanumeric characters together(one after the other). In this case the output will be

abc x.*yz 
a*.BC xyz

How would I find just the names that have 2 non alphanumeric chars together(one after the other)

Comment: Use the pattern `'%[^A-Z0-9][^A-Z0-9]%'`

Comment: Thanks. I want to ignore the spaces. How would I exclude that?

Comment: Remove them before the pattern test; `... where patindex('%[^A-Z0-9]%[^A-Z0-9]%', replace(Surname, ' ', '')) + ...`